# facebook reactions to be grouped by aggs terms elasticsearch

Tags: facebook-graph-api, elasticsearch

I am working on Facebook analytic, Here is a query which is supposed to fetch the summary of the reactions from  Facebook page posts, 
Note: posts json is as it is inserted to elastic-search db

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "from.id": "[Page-id]"
    }
  },
     "aggs": {
       "summary_reaction": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "reactions.data.type.keyword"
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Only issue is query return unique count whereas it should consider all reactions.

My result is

```
"aggregations": {
    "reaction_summary": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "LIKE",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "HAHA",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

here is the sample json

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 6.158189,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "facebook_page",
        "_type": "post",
        "_id": "AV1RMRKSSM3OTvGpqzx7",
        "_score": 6.158189,
        "_source": {
          "reactions": {
            "paging": {
              "cursors": {
                "after": "TVRFMk9EYzVOekl5TWpjMU5USTJPakUxTURBek1EVTNOREU2TWpVME1EazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD",
                "before": "TVRFMk9EYzVOekl5TWpjMU5USTJPakUxTURBek1EVTNOREU2TWpVME1EazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD"
              }
            },
            "data": [
              {
                "pic_large": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=4dcc9a9bbdfc965eb477a14775f31448&oe=5A0BCFB5&__gda__=1510661157_f329dd30b13490dbae8d05d3aa45d79f",
                "type": "LIKE",
                "id": "116879722275526",
                "name": "Moojaa"
              }
            ]
          },
          "from": {
            "picture": {
              "data": {
                "url": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=24cc256b24e5da70f306afcf784a636d&oe=59FBA1D4&__gda__=1509895651_44acee6189c7c1cb6eed023a6e742d1a",
                "is_silhouette": false
              }
            },
            "name": "Moojaa",
            "id": "116879722275526"
          },
          "coordinates": {},
          "created_time": "2017-07-17T15:35:35+0000",
          "message": "Kuthey e Moojaa",
          "type": "status",
          "id": "116879722275526_116886608941504"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "facebook_page",
        "_type": "post",
        "_id": "AV1RMRViSM3OTvGpqzx8",
        "_score": 6.158189,
        "_source": {
          "reactions": {
            "paging": {
              "cursors": {
                "after": "TVRFMk9EYzVOekl5TWpjMU5USTJPakUxTURBek1EUTBNRGc2TWpVME1EazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD",
                "before": "TVRBd01ERTFOREl5TkRrNE56Y3dPakUxTURBek1EUTFNams2TWpVME1EazJNVFl4TXc9PQZDZD"
              }
            },
            "data": [
              {
                "pic_large": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16864759_114731265717623_8811777667276972672_n.jpg?oh=836c6d5145bc8023d3ac60e0dfd42bde&oe=5A00D0DC&__gda__=1509885772_ad8923f4369250c2c2051c5e9293331f",
                "type": "LIKE",
                "id": "111467022710714",
                "name": "Ram Singh Shankar"
              },
              {
                "pic_large": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=4dcc9a9bbdfc965eb477a14775f31448&oe=5A0BCFB5&__gda__=1510661157_f329dd30b13490dbae8d05d3aa45d79f",
                "type": "LIKE",
                "id": "116879722275526",
                "name": "Moojaa"
              }
            ]
          },
          "from": {
            "picture": {
              "data": {
                "url": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=24cc256b24e5da70f306afcf784a636d&oe=59FBA1D4&__gda__=1509895651_44acee6189c7c1cb6eed023a6e742d1a",
                "is_silhouette": false
              }
            },
            "name": "Moojaa",
            "id": "116879722275526"
          },
          "coordinates": {},
          "comments": {
            "paging": {
              "cursors": {
                "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEUyT0RneE5UUTRPVFF5TURFd09qRTFNREF6TURRMk5Eaz0ZD",
                "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEUyT0RneE5EUXlNamMxTXpVME9qRTFNREF6TURRMk1URT0ZD"
              }
            },
            "data": [
              {
                "message": "test",
                "from": {
                  "picture": {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16864759_114731265717623_8811777667276972672_n.jpg?oh=836c6d5145bc8023d3ac60e0dfd42bde&oe=5A00D0DC&__gda__=1509885772_ad8923f4369250c2c2051c5e9293331f",
                      "is_silhouette": false
                    }
                  },
                  "name": "Ram Singh Shankar",
                  "id": "111467022710714"
                },
                "id": "116880885608743_116881442275354"
              },
              {
                "message": "test 2",
                "from": {
                  "picture": {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16864759_114731265717623_8811777667276972672_n.jpg?oh=836c6d5145bc8023d3ac60e0dfd42bde&oe=5A00D0DC&__gda__=1509885772_ad8923f4369250c2c2051c5e9293331f",
                      "is_silhouette": false
                    }
                  },
                  "name": "Ram Singh Shankar",
                  "id": "111467022710714"
                },
                "id": "116880885608743_116881548942010"
              }
            ]
          },
          "created_time": "2017-07-17T15:13:23+0000",
          "message": "another Mooja",
          "type": "status",
          "id": "116879722275526_116880885608743"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "facebook_page",
        "_type": "post",
        "_id": "AV1RMRgtSM3OTvGpqzx9",
        "_score": 6.158189,
        "_source": {
          "reactions": {
            "paging": {
              "cursors": {
                "after": "TVRBd01ERTFOREl5TkRrNE56Y3dPakUxTURBek1EUXpPRGM2TnpnNE5qUTRNRE0zT1RFek16RXkZD",
                "before": "TVRFMk9EYzVOekl5TWpjMU5USTJPakUxTURBek1EUTVOVEk2TnpnNE5qUTRNRE0zT1RFek16RXkZD"
              }
            },
            "data": [
              {
                "pic_large": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=4dcc9a9bbdfc965eb477a14775f31448&oe=5A0BCFB5&__gda__=1510661157_f329dd30b13490dbae8d05d3aa45d79f",
                "type": "HAHA",
                "id": "116879722275526",
                "name": "Moojaa"
              },
              {
                "pic_large": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16864759_114731265717623_8811777667276972672_n.jpg?oh=836c6d5145bc8023d3ac60e0dfd42bde&oe=5A00D0DC&__gda__=1509885772_ad8923f4369250c2c2051c5e9293331f",
                "type": "HAHA",
                "id": "111467022710714",
                "name": "Ram Singh Shankar"
              }
            ]
          },
          "from": {
            "picture": {
              "data": {
                "url": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=24cc256b24e5da70f306afcf784a636d&oe=59FBA1D4&__gda__=1509895651_44acee6189c7c1cb6eed023a6e742d1a",
                "is_silhouette": false
              }
            },
            "name": "Moojaa",
            "id": "116879722275526"
          },
          "coordinates": {},
          "comments": {
            "paging": {
              "cursors": {
                "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEUyT0RneE9ESTFOakE0TmpRNU9qRTFNREF6TURRM05EYz0ZD",
                "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVEUyT0RneE5UVTRPVFF5TURBNU9qRTFNREF6TURRMk5UUT0ZD"
              }
            },
            "data": [
              {
                "message": "test 3",
                "from": {
                  "picture": {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=4dcc9a9bbdfc965eb477a14775f31448&oe=5A0BCFB5&__gda__=1510661157_f329dd30b13490dbae8d05d3aa45d79f",
                      "is_silhouette": false
                    }
                  },
                  "name": "Moojaa",
                  "id": "116879722275526"
                },
                "id": "116880192275479_116881558942009"
              },
              {
                "message": "test ram",
                "from": {
                  "picture": {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16864759_114731265717623_8811777667276972672_n.jpg?oh=836c6d5145bc8023d3ac60e0dfd42bde&oe=5A00D0DC&__gda__=1509885772_ad8923f4369250c2c2051c5e9293331f",
                      "is_silhouette": false
                    }
                  },
                  "name": "Ram Singh Shankar",
                  "id": "111467022710714"
                },
                "id": "116880192275479_116881578942007"
              },
              {
                "message": "test singh",
                "from": {
                  "picture": {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://fb-s-a-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/16864759_114731265717623_8811777667276972672_n.jpg?oh=836c6d5145bc8023d3ac60e0dfd42bde&oe=5A00D0DC&__gda__=1509885772_ad8923f4369250c2c2051c5e9293331f",
                      "is_silhouette": false
                    }
                  },
                  "name": "Ram Singh Shankar",
                  "id": "111467022710714"
                },
                "id": "116880192275479_116881598942005"
              },
              {
                "message": "khair",
                "from": {
                  "picture": {
                    "data": {
                      "url": "https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-fbx/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/20108099_116879808942184_8792637908147052517_n.png?oh=4dcc9a9bbdfc965eb477a14775f31448&oe=5A0BCFB5&__gda__=1510661157_f329dd30b13490dbae8d05d3aa45d79f",
                      "is_silhouette": false
                    }
                  },
                  "name": "Moojaa",
                  "id": "116879722275526"
                },
                "id": "116880192275479_116881825608649"
              }
            ]
          },
          "created_time": "2017-07-17T15:10:12+0000",
          "message": "Testing my Mooja",
          "type": "status",
          "id": "116879722275526_116880192275479"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't get it 'it should consider all reactions', isn't the aggregator counting all. can you share some example

Comment: I mean elasticsearch consider single reaction from each post, there are 3 posts with 2 unique "LIKES" and 1 unique "HAHA" whereas in total 3 posts have 3 "likes" and 2 "HAHA" reactions.

Comment: thanks, i will take a look

Answer (score 1):

You have to set data inside the reactions as [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/mapping-nested-type.html) and you can do nested aggregation on the data to get all the counts for the type.

Mappings

```
PUT facebook_index1
{
  "mappings": {
    "document_type" : {
      "properties": {
        "reactions" : {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "data" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "properties" : {
                "type" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

use [nested aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) to aggregate for type for data.

```
POST facebook_index1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_data_aggs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "reactions.data"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "summary_reaction": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "reactions.data.type",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: Do we have any alternative other than changing mapping, otherwise I will go with this solution

Comment: not now in my mind, but i think data is association and can be better represented with nested data types